# Нужна помощь с деплоем веб-приложения Rails в Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пользуюсь одним гайдом по деплою веб-приложений в Capistrano. Попалась вот такая штука:

> -i188.226.255.173

Предлагается "вставить свой IP вместо этого". Выдает ошибку - скорее всего, неправильный формат IP-адреса. Что это за "i"? Как следует вставлять адрес?

U.P.D. Код ошибки

> 6.1.74, playbook.yml
>   Usage: ansible-playbook playbook.yml
>
> ansible-playbook: error: no such option: -9

Comment: Текста ошибки не хватает.

Comment: Это весь текст)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, **ваш вопрос далеко не про Capistrano**, а по Ansible.

Опция `-i` указывает Ansible на [файл с инвентарем](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html). Хак в виде `-i "188.226.255.173,"` позволяет обойтись без этого файла.

Судя по ошибке, у вас где то косяк в самом playbook.